# Tshark and web-server response time

Tags: linux, shell, unix, traffic, tshark

How can I get response time difference between GET and HTTP/1.0 200 OK with using of tshark&shell or something else for each hostname? 
What can you recommend me for answering this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend both `wireshark` and `tshark` using Lua scripts. See [Chapter 11](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/wsluarm.html) of the Wireshark documentation for details. I would start by trying to write a [Tap/Listener](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Taps) that inspects HTTP "packets" that have been preprocessed by `wireshark` to collect the data and use the tap's `reset` method to perform calculations and output.